# Can I connect Amazon fire TV/fire TV stick to my Macbook Pro instead of TV?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, television

If I just replace a TV with Macbook Pro, does it work? I haven't tested it yet. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon Fire TV requires a TV with an HDMI *input* channel to display video, something MacBooks (or pretty much any computer) are lacking. So no, this will not work (it won't work with an Apple TV/MacBook combination either).

Comment: You might manage to make it work with an iMac that has Target Display Mode and a suitable HDMI to DisplayPort or Thunderbolt adaptor. But not with any Apple laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You must have an INPUT port on your Mac in order for this to work.  Unfortunately they only come with OUTPUT ports...sorry....no FireStick to Mac capability!

Answer (score -3):

Yes, as long as you have an HDMI port in your Mac. If you don't, you can buy a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

Comment: The HDMI port on every Mac that has one is *HDMI output* not HDMI input.  See the answer from patrix above.